# How to add mouse enter and mouse leave effect in CSS class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a box class in CSS.

```
.box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 290px!important;
    background-color:#FDFEFE;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
```

That i am using to display items in HTML page like this.

```
<div class='box'>
    <ng-include src="'commonTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

How to add mouse enter and mouse leave effect here??

What i want to when user enter mouse in box area change its bg-color to some xyz color and on mouse leave change bg color to original color.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class:

```css
.box {
   background-color: #FFF;
   /* rest of styles */
}
.box:hover {
   background-color: #EEE;
}
```